# Django memcached negative value

Tags: django, memcached, python-2.6

What happens here?

When I initialize a cache key with a negative value I can't use incr and decr. Get does work as expected.

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.set('qwerty',-2)
>>> cache.incr('qwerty')
*** ValueError: Key ':1:qwerty' not found
```

If I do it with a positive number I do get the expected behavior

```
>>> cache.set('qwerty',2)
>>> cache.incr('qwerty')
>>> cache.get('qwerty')
3
```

Comment: Note that setting the cache backend to local memory (django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache) also solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a restriction in memcache. It is only possible to increment/decrement unsinged integers.